# old information for appositive structure

Tags: appositives

> 1.Malaysia,one of the Southeast Asia country, is the host country of the 2016 SEA Game.
>
> 2.Malaysia, the host country of the 2016 SEA Game, is one of the Southeast Asia country.

Which sentence is more meaningful.?
I prefer No.1 as we can easily know Malaysia is a Southeast Asia country and it is not new information.

Comment: Yes, the first one is better but **country** in **the host country** is redundant since you've already used this word in the appositive.

Comment: "one of the Southeast *Asian countries*". Which one is better is only a matter of emphasis (which one you want to tie closer to Malaysia).